# Setting onDragListener for my Map?

Tags: android, dictionary, drag, osmdroid

so I am using osmdroid map and am trying to set a listener when a user drags the map around like this.

```
mapView.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            Log.i(PREFS_NAME, "X:" + String.valueOf(event.getX()));
            Log.i(PREFS_NAME, "Y:" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Now, everything works fine, but when I put this code in program exits with an error.

Is this the right thing to use anyway as the reason for this is that I want to get notified whenever a user moves around the map. I want to be able to check where user moves the map, hence the getX and getY I am watching. The reason for this is that I can stop the map movement if it goes out of bounds I set.

Is this the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

MapViews don't respond to touch events like `onClick()` and `onLongPress()`.  What I would do is before `onCreate()` add this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    float x = ev.getX();
    float y = ev.getY();
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

`x` and `y` will now contain the screen coordinates that the user pressed.  Hope this helps!